# Why do g++ and clang break the namespace abstraction in this case?

Tags: c++, namespaces, g++, overloading, clang

This compiles:

```
struct str {};

namespace a
{
    void foo(str s) {}
}
namespace b
{
    void foo(str s) {}

    void bar(str s) { foo(s); }
}
int main(int, char**)
{
    return 0;
}
```

but this doesn't (with the struct definition moved inside namespace a)

```
namespace a
{
    struct str {};

    void foo(str s) {}
}
namespace b
{
    void foo(a::str s) {}

    void bar(a::str s) { foo(s); }
}
int main(int, char**)
{
    return 0;
}
```

The error I get is

```
bad.cpp: In function ‘void b::bar(a::str)’:
bad.cpp:12: error: call of overloaded ‘foo(a::str&)’ is ambiguous
bad.cpp:10: note: candidates are: void b::foo(a::str)
bad.cpp:5: note:                 void a::foo(a::str)
```

It seems reasonable to expect that, since a::foo is not in scope, the call to foo can only refer to b::foo. 
Is there a good reason for compilation to fail (and if so, what is it), or is it a deficiency in the implementations (of both major compilers)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because of the way name lookup, and in particular [**Argument-Dependent Lookup (ADL)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup), works. When deciding which functions may be a candidate for resolving your call, the compiler will first look up names in:

1. The namespace where the function call occurs;
2. The namespace(s) where the type(s) of the argument(s) is/are defined.

If no function with that name is found in those namespaces, the compiler will proceed inspecting parent namespaces of the namespace where the call is made.

---

So what is going on in the examples from your question?

In the first case, `str` is defined in the *global* namespace, and there is no function called `foo()` there. However, there is one in the namespace where the call occurs (`b`): so the compiler has found a valid name, name lookup stops, and overload resolution starts.

But well, there's only one candidate function! So the task is easy here: the compiler invokes `b::foo()`.

In the second case, on the other hand, `str` is defined in the `a` namespace, and when calling `foo(s)`, the compiler will again look in the namespace where the call is made (`b`) and in the namespace where the type of the argument (`str`) is defined - this time, `a`.

So now there are *two* functions with matching names for resolving the call: enter overload resolution! Alas, both functions are equally good (exact matches, no conversion required). Hence, the call is ambiguous.